# Interpreting multivariate big-Oh notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I'm dealing with a situation right now where I have an algorithm whose complexity is determined by three independent variables `l`, `m`, and `n`. One implementation of the algorithm runs in `O((l + m)*log^2(l + m) + (m + n)*log^2(m + n))` time and another runs in `O((l + m + n)*log^2(l + m + n))`. How can I interpret these complexities? Which one would be preferred? In general, if `f` and `g` are functions of `n` variables, how can I determine if `O(f)` is better asymptotically than `O(g)`?

Comment: That depends on `f` and `g`, and which implementation is best depends what argument the *caller* gives. In other words, it's impossible to tell without widening the scope of the question.

Comment: @aioobe Ok. Then considering I know nothing about `l`, `m`, or `n`, is it still possible for me to determine which of my two given algorithms would be more efficient? What if all three variables were close to each other?

Comment: If they're close to each other, replace them all with `x` for instance.

Comment: Then they're asymptotically equivalent. Is it good enough, then, to continue this process for cases like `m ~ n` and `l` small until I get a decent understanding of which algorithm would be more suited for my application?

Comment: I'm no expert but it sounds to me like that's the case.

Comment: I wrapped up my comments in an answer since it seems like we're reaching a conclusion here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> how can I determine if `O(f)` is better asymptotically than `O(g)`?

That depends on the relation between `f` and `g`, i.e. it depends on what actual arguments the caller uses. It's in other words impossible to answer the question without widening the scope of it.

If you have implicit knowledge of the behavior of the values (for instance if the values are bound to follow each other in magnitude) you could equate them and for instance replace them with `x`.

If the decision has practical implications for you I suggest you implement both algorithms and try them out in practice to include the constant factors on the execution time.

Answer (score 1):

In general, it is possible for two functions to be incomparable. It could be that regardless of the constants c_1 and c_2, for some values of the inputs, c_1 f > c_2 g while for other inputs, c_1 f < c_2 g.

For these particular functions, if the variables l, m, and n are at least 1, **your two bounds are equivalent**: f=O(g) and g=O(f).

Let h(x) = x log^2 x. h(l+m)+h(m+n) is within a constant of h(l+m+n) as long as l,m,n>=1.

Without loss of generality, assume n>=l, so

```
m+n>=l+m 
log(m+n)>=log(l+m)
log^2(m+n)>=log^2(l+m)
h(m+n) >= h(l+m)
```

Then we can use that h is increasing where log is positive.

```
h(l+m)+h(m+n) <= 2 h(m+n) <= 2 h(l+m+n).

h(l+m+n) <= h((l+m)+(m+n)) 
         <= h(2(m+n))
          = 2(m+n)log^2(2(m+n))
          = 2(m+n)(log 2 + log(m+n))^2
         <= 2(m+n)(2log(m+n))^2
         <= 8(m+n)log^2(m+n)
          = 8h(m+n)
         <= 8(h(l+m)+h(m+n)).
```

Sharper estimates may be possible, but this shows that the two estimates are equivalent when the values of l, m, and n are at least 1. (These functions do not differ only by a constant factor when all of the variables are close to 0, so some assumption pushing l+m and m+n away from 0 was necessary.)

Comment: @Juan Lopes: Your answer had valuable content that I think was fixable.